# Python binary search readline does not return whole line

Tags: python

There's lots of help on binary searching here, but can't find this specific problem. This is what I'm getting in IDLE and the same thing is happening in my code.

First, I find the file size of the file to be searched (each line is two integers, separated by a tab and sorted by first integer):

```
>>> import os
>>> a=os.path.getsize("C:\\testfile.txt")
>>> a
9341L
```

Open the file

```
>>> f = open("C:\\testfile.txt",'r')
```

Seek to middle of file (before doing tests for binary search etc.)

```
>>> f.seek(int(a/2))
'\n'
```

the line should be `'534\t1026\n'`

i.e. NOT the whole line, but the rest of the line starting from the 'seek' point. None of the binary search code I have found seem to say how to get the whole line for each new 'seek'.

Thanks,

S.

Solved, thanks Hugh.

Comment: I didn't realise getsize was the problem. The problem is that all the info on readline() says that it reads the entire line, not that it ever reads just the remainder of a line. The solution from Hugh seems simple though, just do readline() twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(shrug) for ten-character lines, there is a 90% chance that a random read will start in the middle of a line.

I suggest you start reading ten characters early - the first readline() will probably get a partial line, the second readline() will get the first guaranteed full line.